# Categories of engineering plants

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, control-engineering

I was wondering if there is a way to categorize engineering plants, or, whether my question is too broad. Cause, there are many big factories out there, and I was wondering whether there are one of more ways, to group them into categories, and what the corresponding taxonomies are and what they describe.

Perhaps the answers can be intentionally broad here. Still, in that case, I would like to have some more or less generic categories.

Thank you for your help, and thank you for getting me startd in this area is interest of mine.

Thanks.

Comment: Engineering and plant do not go together.  Engineering is about design while a plant is about production.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself if such categorization is useful to begin with. What would you use such a thing for? Things are what they are so unless there is some use to categorizing things this way, they tend not to be categorized. That's also why sometimes categories of things are a bit fuzzy at the boundaries with regards to the exact definition  they aren't meant to be rigorous and clearly delineate things, but useful most of the time (usually to speed up communication).

Comment: Like asking about how many types of engineers there are...

Comment: please define what an "engineering plant" is.  A factory that produces engineers?

Comment: I was mainly asking about industrial plants.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, there are two types of plants, "commercial plants" and "industrial plants", and both require a detailed "engineering design".

As the name suggests, the commercial plant is a building usually having a large footprint and devoted to commercial uses, such as warehouses, shopping centers, data centers, distribution centers...

Industrial plants can be further categorized as "heavy industrial plants", "light industrial plants", "manufacturing plants", "mining plants", and/or other "specialty production plants". In general, industrial plants usually house those "production equipment and workers" necessary for producing goods, as opposed to the commercial plants, which store/house/distribute the finished products for consumption.

Some of the building classification overlaps, such as the warehouses, depends on the content it stores, a warehouse can either be a commercial plant or an industrial plant.